# Mozilla cookie export format fields

Tags: firefox, cookies, mozilla

I'd like to be able to import cookies from firefox into my program (and export them to firefox if needed). There is an ff extension, which lets me export cookies to a text file, and I'm  planning to use that.

What it does is to create files which look like this:

```
<domain>        <unknown> <path> <secure>    <expires> <name>  <value>
.doubleclick.net    TRUE    /      FALSE    1384930871  _drt_   NO_DATA
.doubleclick.net    TRUE    /      FALSE    1447959674  id      221d59c8c3010099||t=1384287663|et=730|cs=002213fd482bafde14396835b8
```

What is the meaning of the `<unknown>` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it is the HttpOnly attribute, but to be sure you should check the extension's code.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer might be **WRONG**. Many addons including Firebug adopt the [Netscape standard format](http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/#3.5), where the second column is a flag:

> From left-to-right, here is what each field represents:
> **domain** - The domain that created AND that can read the variable.
> **flag** - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if all machines within a given domain can access the variable. This value is set automatically by the browser, depending on the value you set for domain.
> **path** - The path within the domain that the variable is valid for.
> **secure** - A TRUE/FALSE value indicating if a secure connection with the domain is needed to access the variable.
> **expiration** - The UNIX time that the variable will expire on. UNIX time is defined as the number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.
> **name** - The name of the variable.
> **value** - The value of the variable.

This format is also used by [curl](https://curl.se/docs/http-cookies.html):

> Field number, what type and example data and the meaning of it:
>
> 1. string example.com - the domain name
> 2. boolean FALSE - include subdomains
> 3. string /foobar/ - path
> 4. boolean TRUE - send/receive over HTTPS only
> 5. number 1462299217 - expires at - seconds since Jan 1st 1970, or 0
> 6. string person - name of the cookie
> 7. string daniel - value of the cookie